# Spark changelog issue, changelog doesn't exists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes, bigdata, spark-streaming

I am facing this issue with my spark job. The job was running fine for long time but now I see this issue. I am not able to find a solution please help me.

We are running this on Kubernetes.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading streaming state file of s3a://table-onlineofflineinternet-store/checkpointing/abcd/temp_table/state/0/6/563042.changelog does not exist. 
If the stream job is restarted with a new or updated state operation, please create a new checkpoint location or clear the existing checkpoint location.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreChangelogReader.liftedTree1$1(StateStoreChangelog.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreChangelogReader.<init>(StateStoreChangelog.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDBFileManager.getChangelogReader(RocksDBFileManager.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDB.$anonfun$replayChangelog$1(RocksDB.scala:196)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcVJ$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcVJ$sp.java:23)
    at scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.foreach(NumericRange.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDB.replayChangelog(RocksDB.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDB.load(RocksDB.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDBStateStoreProvider.getReadStore(RocksDBStateStoreProvider.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDBStateStoreProvider.getReadStore(RocksDBStateStoreProvider.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStore$.getReadOnly(StateStore.scala:492)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.ReadStateStoreRDD.compute(StateStoreRDD.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
```

I would like spark community to see how I can resolve this, my spark code is written in scala juts FYI.

Answer (score 0):

s3's not a real filesytem; files written to it only become visible during close(), so if a process dies any changelog being written isn't visible. Are you confident the spark streaming checkpointer you are using is compatible with S3? where confident means "is it clearly documented that it works?

- you can use the s3 console to look for incomplete uploads, to see if something was being written -there's not much you can do there.
- if your hadoop libraries are 3.3.2+, you can set `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.downgrade.syncable.exceptions` to `false` then any attempt by the checkpointer to use the filesystem hflush/hsync apis to persist data will fail fast. This doesn't fix your problem, but it will confirm that an incompatible checkpointer is in use.
- as for a fix: find an s3 compatible checkpointer or use different storage such as EBS for saving checkpoints

Apache Spark's documentation covers [Spark Streaming and Object Storage](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cloud-integration.html#spark-streaming-and-object-storage). In particular, it mentions the `AbortableStreamBasedCheckpointFileManager` checkpointer needed for safe checkpointing on S3 Storage

Comment: So if I do this , what about my previous checkpointings in s3 if I use EBS, won't my data get lost and it will create checkpointing from scratch.

Comment: Also my last checkpointing was for 28dec and kafka holds only data for last 7 days , we have set it to default configuration. 

Even if I do change in checkpoint location I won’t be able to retrieve data from 28 dec to 7 Jan . 

Please share your insights

Comment: no idea. All i know is "s3 is not a real filesystem and trying to use checkpointing which makes that assumption is not going to recover from failures".

Comment: l@AdityaVerma added a link to the official spark docs on the topic -it does include an S3 compatible checkpointer but you have to explicitly ask for it.